# Why such coordinates are still called "isothermal" in the Lorentz case?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, terminology, wave-equation, semi-riemannian-geometry

We know that in a two dimensional Riemannian manifold there always is, at least locally, a coordinate system in which $g_{ij} = \lambda^2 \delta_{ij}$ - such coordinates are called isothermal. There are great answers such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18544/why-are-they-called-isothermal-coordinates) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32169/why-are-they-called-isothermal-coordinates) explaining the reason for such name, since any such coordinate system ${\bf x}$ satisfies $\triangle {\bf x} = 0$, being a stationary solution to the heat equation.

However, for a two dimensional Lorentz manifold, there is also, locally, a coordinate system in with $g_{ij} = \lambda^2 \eta_{ij}$, where $\eta_{ij}$ is the Minkowski metric, say, $\eta_{11} = -\eta_{22}=1$ and $\eta_{12}=0$. As far as I have seen, such coordinate systems are also called isothermal. This bothers me a bit, since in this case we must have $$\Box {\bf x} \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\partial^2 {\bf x}}{\partial u^2}-\frac{\partial^2 {\bf x}}{\partial v^2}=0,$$and so ${\bf x}$ is a solution of the wave equation, not the heat equation. Is there a more appropriate name for such coordinates that I somehow missed? Can someone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: I agree it's a bad name. It's okay to call them all Laplacian's no matter which metric you are using. Just call them harmonic, no need to introduce a word that has misleading physics attatched.

Comment: For what it is worth: I've never seen such a coordinate system called _isothermal_ in the Lorentzian context. Also, the existence of the locally "isothermal" coordinate system is actually much easier to construct in the Lorentzian case, by first passing through the null coordinate system where the metric is only off-diagonal. Most places I've seen emphasize the null coordinate system over the "isothermal" one. Lastly, the condition that $\Box \mathbf{x} = 0$ is frequently called the "wave coordinate condition".