# Why is the number of negative dimensions of a quadratic form called "Inertia"?

Tags: definition, math-history, quadratic-forms

Why is the number of negative dimensions of a quadratic form called "Inertia"?

See [Space—Time—Matter by Hermann Weyl](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43006) page 44, following equation (16) for an example of this usage.

Comment: Because it remains unchanged with a basis change.

Comment: So it is "inert"?  I guess that might have been the original motivation for the designation, but there are plenty of other such numbers, to include the number of dimensions.  Do you have an authoritative reference?

Comment: possibly defined by Sylvester  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Comment: not actually named  but ... https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/sylv/inertia.pdf

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/why-is-it-called-sylvesters-law-of-inertia