# What do you call $x$ if $x^n=1$ in general structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

If $x^n=0$, we say $x$ is nilpotent. What do you call $x$ if $x^n=1$? I'm searching for a word that encompasses roots of unity, rational rotations, reflections, primitive elements of finite fields, and so forth.

- Idempotent is taken: $x$ is idempotent if $x^2=x$.
- Unipotent is taken: $x$ is unipotent if $x-1$ is nilpotent.

If no such word exists, I propose "identipotent" :)

Comment: Maybe *unit*, or *$n$'th root of unity*?

Comment: See also [torsion (element)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_(algebra)), which unifies additive and multiplicative terminology.

Comment: Indeed, you definitely have to include root of unity, so then I propose "identipotentrooti". Better to call it "torson element", though. Matrices $A$ with $A^n=I$ are also called *periodic*.

Comment: Primitive elements in a finite field are *not* characterized by a single equation of the type $x^n = 1$.  Primitive elements in a finite field are examples of generators of a cyclic group, and the generator of a (nontrivial) cyclic group is not described as the solution to just one equation like $x^n = 1$.   Anyway, nobody is going to use new terminology for what you describe since we have made it this far in math with the terms we already have, like "torsion element".

Comment: @Dietrich Re: colorful math terms: given that Sylvester probably coined orders of magnitude more terms than any other mathematician I wouldn't be suprised if he already proposed one. He once appended a five-page "Glossary of new or unusual Terms, or of Terms used in a new or unusual sense in the preceding Memoir" (genesis of "inertia" for quadratic forms). A partial list of Sylvester's colorful terminology is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7044/242).

Comment: But "torsion" is not due to Sylvester. [Jeff Miller](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/t/) wrote:  'According to Howard Eves in A Survey of Geometry, vol. II (1965), The name torsion was introduced by L. I. Valleé in 1825, replacing an older name flexion" [James A. Landau] ... This terminology seems to have arisen around 1930. Its origin lies in algebraic (or combinatorial) topology. Poincaré ( Proc. London Math. Soc, vol. 32 (1900), 277-308) defined torsion coefficients for manifolds (variétés), and he distinguished manifolds with and without torsion...[Peter Flor]'